# Convexity of $f(x,y)=xy^2$ on $y=x , x\ge0 $

Tags: functions

I asked earlier about the convexity of $x^3$ with $x \ge 0$  and it is now solved thanks to the genius here. I know it is convex.

What if we change it a little bit?
Set
$f(x,y) =xy^2$ on $y=x, x \ge0$

Intuitively, I think it is convex. And I have proved it with the formula
$f(\vec{x}) \ge f(\vec{y})+\nabla f(\vec{y})^T(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$ .
But when I tried to prove it by showing its Hessian is positive semidefinite, I have an opposite result:
Heassian of $f$  at $(a,a)$  where $a \ge 0$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \phantom{a}  \phantom{a} 2a \\ 2a  \phantom{a} 2a \end{bmatrix}$. 
$\det (F- \lambda I)=0 $ gives $\lambda ^2 -2a \lambda -4a^2=0$ and thus, $ \lambda =a(1 + \sqrt{5}) \ge 0$ or $\lambda =a(1 - \sqrt{5})<0 $

Where did I misunderstand? I am certain I have made no calculation mistakes but now I have two oppposite answers so something must be wrong.

I am now really self-studying everything now and I really help.

Many thanks

Comment: [It's not convex.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x,+y)+%3D+xy%5E2)

Comment: @TheoBendit  As a function of 2 variables, the OP's function is not convex. But he is asking about something else, namely a 1 dimensional restriction of the function.  And that one is convex.

Comment: The proper term is "convexity" not "convexness".

Comment: Usually the concept of convexity assumes that your function is defined on some domain (hence open and all its points are interior). In such cases you need your Hessian to be positive definite. But your function is defined on a convex set that is not open. When you compute the Hessian, it is not positive definite because in the direction perpendicular to the line $x=y$ your function is not convex. You have to restrict the quadratic form to  directions $(h,h)$. If you compute $(h,h)^TH(h,h)$ it is positive, hence it is convex along that direction.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much for all the clarification, @GReyes

Answer (score 0):

The functions $f(x,y)=x^3$ and $g(x,y)=xy^2$, when restricted to the line $y=x$, are the same.  They are convex.  Your current trouble comes from misunderstanding the Hessian condition.  What you need for convexity of the restricted function is that the Hessian matrix, when restricted to the subspace of vectors $(u,u)$, is positive semidefinite.  All you need is that $(u,u)H (u,u)'\ge0$ for all real $u$, not that $(u,v)H(u,v)'\ge0$ for all real $u,v$.  The former is true, the latter (as you've  seen) is false.

Comment: So, when it is restricted to a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ , we should not be checking the eigenvalues but check if $\vec{x}^T F \vec{x} \ge 0$ is true for any point in that subspace?

Comment: Yes.  Alternatively, you could pre- & post-multiply $F$ by the projection $P$ onto the subspace in question, and see if $P'FP$ has non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: I understand it. Thank you! @kimchi lover